# SE ads bug - question advertises itself

Tags: bug, status-deferred, advertising

I was browsing rpg.se when I came across an ad for a question that was also on rpg.se - then... wait a minute... it's advertising for itself!

I don't know the algorithm that picks the questions - but perhaps it should do some kind of a check to prevent it from advertising itself?

Freehand circle pic very related:[image]

Comment: Maybe it's asking you for a second opinion? :P

Comment: @Downvoter - I'm curious why you downvoted. I mean, honestly!

Comment: Not to be crass but "so what if it does?"  Does it do it every time you load that question?  The odds seem fairly stacked against it happening and it's not preventing anything or breaking anything when it does.

Comment: Well, there's a couple things. One, it's a bug - even a minor one, it's still worth bringing up. Two, any bug is indicative of potential for other bugs. Now I'm certainly willing to admit that it's low priority, and that it wouldn't bother me if it was never fixed, and that the consequences of leaving it are so low it's ridiculous. But does that mean it shouldn't have been reported just because it was low priority? What if there is already a check to prevent this from happening, but it's getting ignored? Then you have to ask what other checks are ignored. I think it was worth reporting. :)

Comment: And preliminary research indicates there is roughly a 1/10,000,000 chance of this happening on each page view. It's pretty low, although you'd be surprised how fast odds that low over a site as popular as SOFUE something like that could make this happen dozens of times a month. \*gasp\*

Comment: I know this has been declined, but, in relation to it... I saw, on sqa.se, an ad for a question of ~mine~ on rpg.se. Just thought I'd put it on here since it's related and you never know - interns need projects too!

Comment: Just saw this myself - http://i.imgur.com/qJNTP.png

Comment: @Aleadam: I LOL'd

Comment: This issue was reported in 2011. Does it still happen in 2017?

Comment: It happens on the side bar with great regularity. The ads themselves no longer serve ANY ads for questions, so obviously it can't happen for them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Awesome, but it seems low priority.

Comment: I am moving this up to priority ∞ + 1.

Comment: @Jeff to be fair, it has happened a second time in as many months. Maybe that can justify increasing to priority `infinite / 2`?

Comment: Awesome, seems very high priority.

Comment: @Jeff so now it's at priority (∞ - 1) I guess :)

Comment: @JeffAtwood Isn't that "INFINITY PLUS ONE", not "INFINITE PLUS ONE"?

Comment: 36 people have voted this question up :-O http://i.imgur.com/JqYTmjn.gifv

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo Don't you know Infinity + 1 is NaN, and (Infinity + 1) - 1 is also NaN? Learn you a IEEE 754 :P