# Is it normal that I get StackExchange advertisement about the same site I'm on?

Tags: bug, advertising

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SE ads bug - question advertises itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93138/se-ads-bug-question-advertises-itself)

Here's is a jewel of the Stack Exchange advertisement, that is ... not at his best. Not only it's about a question that is on the same site I'm on. But the question is actually right next to the advertisement. Is this normal ?

[image]

Comment: Well this one is slightly different and more broad, I don't think advertisement about the same site I'm on should be shown. It shouldn't be limited to don't show the same question that I'm viewing.

Answer (score -1):

This might in one way be a great feature, highlighting a question on the site that already has visitors likely to follow that link...you'd be pretty pleased as the OP I'd imagine.