# Cross site promotion links to the question I'm viewing

Tags: bug, site-crossover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SE ads bug - question advertises itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93138/se-ads-bug-question-advertises-itself)

[image: Screenshot with a question, and the same question featuring in the cross site promotion]

Yo dawg, I heard you liked the question [Did any writing systems exist before kanji was imported?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/did-any-writing-systems-exist-before-kanji-was-imported). So I put [Did any writing systems exist before kanji was imported?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/did-any-writing-systems-exist-before-kanji-was-imported) in the sidebar, so you can visit [Did any writing systems exist before kanji was imported?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/did-any-writing-systems-exist-before-kanji-was-imported) while you're reading [Did any writing systems exist before kanji was imported?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/did-any-writing-systems-exist-before-kanji-was-imported) .

Comment: It would have been much funnier if this question would have been closed as a duplicate of itself.